# Align data into rows using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to align these data in to rows in Excel using VBA.I have a huge data in this format. I need to make it into rows

```
SUBSCRIBER DETAILS
IMSI             MSISDN           STATE
405845001382775  919085919027     IDLE

DATE             TIME             CELLID
130103           122725           404-29-12906-15353

IMEI
356395024630200

SUBSCRIBER DETAILS
IMSI             MSISDN           STATE
405845002463183  919085325090     IDET

DATE             TIME             CELLID
130103           103447           404-29-12107-23993

IMEI
354917031429730
```

Required output:-

```
IMSI        MSISDN           STATE  DATE             TIME             CELLID            DATE             TIME             CELLID            IMEI
405845001382775  919085919027     IDLE              130103           122725           404-29-12906-15353            356395024630200
IMSI             MSISDN           STATE DATE             TIME             CELLID            DATE             TIME             CELLID            IMEI
405845002463183  919085325090     IDET              130103           103447           404-29-12107-23993            354917031429730
```

Comment: Is `aline` a new function, property to use? It is `Align` ;) Can you please record a macro to align data and then post the code if there are bugs or if you get stuck?

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that your data are in blocks over several rows and you'd like to get them into one row?

Comment: Suppose,the data is pasted in sheet1 in Cell A1.
My requirement is 
1.where it find the string“IMSI” (Suppose IMSI string  is in cell A2),I need the A3 data in B3 Cell.
2. where it find the string “DATE” (Suppose DATE string is in cell A5),I need the A3 data in C5 Cell.
2. where it find the string “IMEI” (Suppose IMEI string is in cell A9),I need the A3 data in D9 Cell.

Similarly it should loop for all data and make it in rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the segment you are looking for.  Use as needed as you have your range selected. Each type of Alignment use in conjunction with the "With Statement"

```
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
End With
```

Comment: Yes Juri, my data are in blocks over several rows and I'd like to get them into one row.
Like the way I have mentioned in "Required output:-" section I mentioned.
Please help me if it is possible in excel using vba.

Please help

Comment: Suppose,the data is pasted in sheet1 in Cell A1.
My requirement is 
1.where it find the string“IMSI” (Suppose IMSI string  is in cell A2),I need the A3 data in B3 Cell.
2. where it find the string “DATE” (Suppose DATE string is in cell A5),I need the A3 data in C5 Cell.
2. where it find the string “IMEI” (Suppose IMEI string is in cell A9),I need the A3 data in D9 Cell.

Similarly it should loop for all data and make it in rows.